# Does SPRING MVP would exist?

Tags: spring-mvc, mvp

I have understood that Spring MVC is very powerfull...but I have read in Google IO 2010 : Architecture recommendation that the MVP pattern is architecturally better that designing a MVC pattern (since it purpose 'n' differents view for one presentation for example). So I have a doubt now, because I want to create an app (with SPRING ROO) but I hesitate to use SPRING MVC or to developp my own MVP pattern as recommended by Google (or to use a MVP-plateform)... I would be satisfied if a SPRING MVP would exist. Does it make sense ? What is your opinion about what I am saying ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Spring MVC to implement the MVP pattern. Which is exactly what Spring roo does. It uses all the basic Spring / Spring MVC components but uses them in a way which conforms to the MVP pattern.

My suggestion would be to create a test project with roo. Follow the instructions here: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/roo-sts.html

Once you do this, start dissecting the Roo project to see how they are implementing the MVP pattern. Be warned it will take a while for you to get  your head around what they are doing. But it'll be worth the effort. Things will seem less magical if you take the time to understand what's happening under the covers.